# How to multicast a Mono to multiple subscribers in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

With what I have read so far, one can multicast a Flux to multiple subscribers using `ConnectableFlux` using something similar to following:

```
Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.range(1, 50)
                .log();

ConnectableFlux<Integer> integerConnectableFlux = integerFlux.publish();

integerConnectableFlux.map(i -> i*2)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

integerConnectableFlux.map(i -> i*3)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

integerConnectableFlux.connect();
```

To my limited understanding of reactive streams, above code converts a cold publisher to a hot publisher.
I am working on scenario where I have multiple subscribers for a `Mono`. How can I get a hot publisher out of a Mono?

Answer (score 3):

Managed to multicast the mono using [`Mono.share()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#share--) operator:

> Prepare a Mono which shares this Mono result similar to Flux.shareNext(). This will effectively turn this Mono into a hot task when the first Subscriber subscribes using subscribe() API. Further Subscriber will share the same Subscription and therefore the same result. It's worth noting this is an un-cancellable Subscription.

**Example:**
Following code creates only one subscription on the publisher:

```
        Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono.just(2)
                .log()
                .share();

        integerMono.map(i -> i+3)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        integerMono.map(i -> i*5)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output of above code is shown below (data is requested only once):

```
5
reactor.Mono.Just.1 - {} - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
reactor.Mono.Just.1 - {} - | request(unbounded)
reactor.Mono.Just.1 - {} - | onNext(2)
reactor.Mono.Just.1 - {} - | onComplete()
10
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`Mono#cache()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--) operator:

> Turn this Mono into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for
> further Subscriber. Completion and Error will also be replayed.